# how can i convert this member table query into linq

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a member table with columns

```
 member_id
 member_lastname
 member_firstname
```

i have another table visits with columns

```
visit_id
member_id
visit_date
```

i have got the mysql query like this

```
string sql =  @"SELECT COUNT('x') AS numVisits, member_firstname as firstname, member_lastname as lastname, members.member_id
                FROM visits, members
                WHERE visits.member_id = members.member_id
                 AND visit_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                GROUP BY member_firstname, member_lastname, members.member_id
                ORDER BY COUNT('x') DESC";
```

How can i convert this query into linq to entities

my entity name is trasitdbcontext

would any one pls give any idea about this ..

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from v in visits
join m in members on v.member_id equals m.member_id
where v.visit_Date >= startDate && v.visit_Date <= endDate
group m by new {  m.member_firstname, m.member_lastname, m.member_id } into g
orderby g.Count()
select new
{
   count = g.Count(),
   member_firstname = g.Key.member_firstname, 
   member_lastname = = g.Key.member_lastname,
   member_id = = g.Key.member_id,
}
```